Quit application by bundle identifier (AppleScript)
I'm trying to quit an application with an AppleScript by providing its bundle identifier.
My code does not work:
tell application "System Events" to quit (application whose bundle identifier is "com.apple.Notes")

or
quit app "com.apple.Safari"

The second code asks where the app to quit is located...


Your second snippet is pretty close, you need application id
quit application id "com.apple.Safari"

